# Table design for random versus

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am developping an application that creates random "battles / versus" of two things that have the same type. Let's say it's about cars and their features for example:

There would be many group of features, things related to safety, to comfort, etc.

Car A would have one security feature, airbags, Car B it would be ABS and air conditioning and Car C heated seats.

Now I have to store a list of versus: airbags vs. ABS, heated seats vs. air conditioning. Note that I can't do airbags vs. heated seats.

I've come up with two ideas to make this work.

#### users

```
id | username
```

#### cars

```
id | name
```

#### groups

```
id | name
```

#### features

```
id | car_id | group_id | value
```

#### versus

**First version**:

```
id | user_id | group_id | car_a_id | car_b_id | winner_id
```

**Second version**:

```
id | user_id | feature_a_id | feature_b_id | winner_id
```

Now with the first version, I have to use `car_a_id`, `car_b_id` and `group_id` to fetch `features` but that ensures I am not comparing features that are not in the same group. The thing is if any feature gets deleted I'll will have an invalid versus and I won't know that until I actually fetch the features.

The second version solves that, since I can just add a `ON DELETE CASCADE` to my foreign keys. But now I have to make sure each feature of a row is in the same group when fetching them (I can't rely on the fact that the list of versus is actually valid).

Now I don't like either of these solutions, I feel like I'm doing something completely wrong but I can't find out anything better.

Is there a better / simpler way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand why there is `user_id` in your tables. Isn't it just one feature beating another? In that case your second solution (without `user_id`) would look better; just make sure you don't insert incompatible features into the table.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Every versus is for a single user, so I have to keep my `user_id`. And the issue is I can't make sure I don't insert incompatible features in there (it'd be out of scope to explain why but I really can't).

Comment: So is the "versus" actually tied to a "feature?" It seems like the "versus" is just comparing two cars with regards to a single "group," which could have any number of features.

Edit: Nevermind, I re-read the question. It sounds like you want to compare features, and not "groups." In this sense, I don't think you want to go with the first approach, since that "versus" is only tied to a group. I would go with the second approach and use constraints to ensure that the "group_id" of both features in a "versus" are equal. 

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented above, but want to post a few solutions.

If a "versus" is a direct feature to feature comparison, you need to directly reference the features in the "versus." This is shown in your "Second version."

It sounds like the main concern is ensuring that both features in a "versus" are of the same group. You can accomplish this in a few different ways.

1. Eliminate the option for users to compare features in different groups via the UI or other code. For example, have drop down boxes that only show the features in a single group when the user is selecting features to compare.
2. You could also try to use subqueries or functions in a postgresql table constraints. I've never done something like this (nor would I recommend it), but it may be suitable for your specific application requirements. http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/052h6ybahr/checking-of-constraints-via-subqueries
3. You could store the group_id of both features in the "versus" table. This definitely violates the rules of normalization, but if you have no control over the calling code and need to ensure the groups do not conflict, you can create a simple constraint such that "feature1_group_id" == "feature2_group_id." Not a robust method, and I wouldn't recommend it, but is another option.

In summary, I think you need to coordinate with the UI to ensure that users cannot violate group membership constraints when comparing features (solution 1).